# Is there an XML schema for the Tomcat 6 context.xml?

Tags: tomcat, xsd, context.xml

NetBeans has great support for showing the nodes and attributes available in an XML, but it needs to load the schema. Is there one for Tomcat's context container XML?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sorry, no. There is no XML schema for context.xml.

Comment: Thanks Mark. As a contributor to Tomcat, is this something you think would benefit the community? I wouldn't attempt to create it myself if there was a reason it hasn't been done yet.

Comment: It is impossible to do correctly since you don't known what the valid attributes may be for a custom Context implementation or any nested custom Valve or any nested resource that is not one of the small number of standard resources Tomcat recognises. I can see how this could be useful in an IDE but also how its use could generate numerous false error reports. On balance I think no schema is the right way to go but the dev list is the best place for a full discussion of the pros and cons of adding a schema. Note this applies to server.xml too. A schema is possible for tomcat-users.xml.